# "About Me" difference

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, design

I have accounts in **[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/484082/blasteralfred)**, **[Super User](https://superuser.com/users/74875/blasteralfred)**, **[Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/15678/blasteralfred)** and **[Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/users/113979/blasteralfred)**. My oldest account is stackoverflow and I use to sync it with other accounts, so that it looks same everywhere. But the "about me" box has got scrollbars in Pro Webmasters and in **[Network Profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/224333)** (it has a comparatively small area). Any fix for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "preview pane"?

Comment: @balpha i mean the rectangle space where our custom details, pics, flair etc appears, on right side of bio

Comment: The regular about me box than? Well, you have a wide picture in your text, so naturally on sites with narrower boxes, you get horizontal scrollbars. I'm not sure what your question is?

Comment: i got it, but is there any possibility to make them wide as seen in stackoverflow? making them wide doesn't make any trouble i think.

Comment: Oh, you want *us* to change something. Sorry, your tags suggested that you want to know what *you* can do (to which the answer obviously is: "don't use such a wide image").

Comment: I want you people, the moderators (or the admins) to change something. Kindly make all pages look alike (only in layout, not in design) so that the trouble won't happen again. Stackoverflow user page layout is nice and fine.

Comment: Yes, I understand that now, that's why I have retagged your question as a feature request.

Comment: @balpha "timestone" thinks that you're a great bro, bro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I disagree that they all have to have the identical width; with tons of different site designs, there should always be a certain amount of freedom for the designers. Thus if you have images in your "about me", you should not try to use available space up to the last pixel.

However, I agree (and so does [Jin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147574/jin), our resident <s>pixel-pusher</s> CSS artist), that the "about me" box in the network profiles on http://stackexchange.com really are unnecessarily narrow, so we'll widen them a bit.

**EDIT**

The "about me" box on network profiles has been widened to match those on beta-themed sites.

Note that your current "about me" still induces the vertical scrollbar, which then causes the box to be narrower, thereby inducing the horizontal scrollbar as well. If you were to create an account on a beta-themed site, you would observe the same behavior. One way to resolve this would be to change your "about me" to use a smaller image.

Comment: Example "about me" on a "random" profile: http://stackexchange.com/users/11683/jon-skeet

Comment: @balpha Is this still true? Programmers is the only site I have found to induce the horizontal scroll bar on mine. SO, MSO, Academia (beta), and Code Review (beta) do not.